# How to send fax through Lotus Notes programmatically

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

I was wondering if anybody knew how to send a fax programmatically using the Lotus Notes API for .NET.  I have used the Domino namespace to get emails from the Lotus email server.  But now I'm wondering if I can fax using the Domino namespace.

This guy makes it seem possible, but does not really give me an idea how to do it. 
http://searchdomino.techtarget.com/expert/KnowledgebaseAnswer/0,289625,sid4_gci1234011,00.html

This link explains how its done in the Lotus application.
http://mscits.wustl.edu/medlib/becker.nsf/WV/A672E84998635AF286256F6C006AAE4C?OpenDocument

Thank you,
-Tesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Domino Fax system works via Lotus Notes email, so you could send a fax the same way you send an email via Notes for .NET, with the recipient set to the fax's address.

Here's one example that shows how to send emails via C#  http://www.notes411.com/dominosource/tips.nsf/0/DB75154E68C49D90802571B600671802!opendocument

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Just to make sure what you are saying. For the email address field, replace it with the fax number?  For example if I'm sending it to Mary Jane and her fax number is 5624544567. Then I use 5624544567 as the email address? Thanks.

Comment: Close, but not exactly.  The number will be part of the address, but it should look like 2025551212@faxserver.  The "faxserver" part of that address is setup in the Domino Directory, and will be whatever your IT department set it up to be.  Talk to the Notes admins to find out how to send a fax in your environment.

Comment: So now that I can send emails through Lotus.  I can come back to this question. I went to my Lotus client and figured out if I put in the To field the following format: HiteshRana@12155555555@fax where HiteshRana is the title, 12155555555 is the fax number(the leading one is needed), and the string "fax". That sent me a fax.  So when I do it through the program the same way, I don't get a fax.  The code I have in my other post about sending emails through lotus is what I'm using.